# Trabalhando com dados do Excel no C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Necessito criar uma aplicação que leia uma pequena sequencia de dados disponibilizados cada em uma coluna do Excel. 
A minha dúvida é se o melhor caminho é tratar direto no SQL fazendo upload do arquivo e depois tratando com uma procedure ou então trabalhar com os dados no C# e enviar os mesmos a cada coluna da minha tabela do SQL.

Tratando do lado do C# acredito que consigo ter mais segurança com relação ao o que estou enviando ao banco, dei uma lida nessa questão: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/how-to-read-data-of-an-excel-file-using-c mas não compreendi muito bem.

Para o exemplo de procedure estou utilizando esse artigo como base: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-Import-Excel-Sheet-data-into-SQL-Server-using-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Olha, não aconselharia voce a usar SQL pra fazer isso. Existem muitas formas de fazer importação de arquivos Excel, mas isso é do seu gosto. Da uma olhada em Closed XML e Open XML.https://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: O que exatamente você não entendeu da outra questão?

Comment: Utilizei parte do código da resposta escolhida para essa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14034/erro-ao-ler-xml . Funcionou perfeitamente. Utilizei o XML pois não estava conseguindo ler o Excel no lado do servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é aconselhável regras de negócio no banco de dados! Somente por este motivo o ideal seria você usar C#.

Recomendo a biblioteca: [LinqToExcel](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/)

Você consegue ler arquivos Excel de forma bem intuitiva:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
var indianaCompanies = from c in excel.Worksheet<Company>()
                       where c.State == "IN"
                       select c;
```