# Melhor maneira para se trabalhar com arquivos XLS e XLSX

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Qual a melhor forma para se trabalhar com planilhas do Excel, XLS e XLSX no C#?

Preciso realizar leituras das células de acordo com o nome da coluna, que está especificada na primeira linha.

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

[image: Planilha Excel]

**Observação:** Dentro do arquivo XLS ou XLSX terá somente uma worksheet

Comment: A Library que costumo usar para manipular e criar planilhas é o [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), com ele você consegue manipular praticamente tudo, [esse](http://blog.fryhard.com/archive/2010/10/28/reading-xlsx-files-using-c-and-epplus.aspx) tutorial ensina a fazer leitura de uma planilha.

Comment: Na forma atual sua pergunta não está boa para os padrões do *site*. [ask] Veja: [help/dont-ask]. Não estou dizendo que a pergunta é toda ruim. Já perguntaram algo parecido e não produziu coisas muito boas. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23080/trabalhando-com-dados-do-excel-no-c

Comment: Obrigado @Laerte pela sua proatividade na edição.

Comment: @TonCunha, você também pode usar [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/), nesse [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855813/npoi-how-to-read-file-using-npoi) tem um exemplo com arquivos XLS, para arquivos XLSX basta importar `XSSF` ao invés de `HSSF`

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso um pacote NuGet chamado **ExcelDataReader**:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/

[O repositório GitHub fica aqui](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader).

Um exemplo:

```
var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

while (excelReader.Read())
{
    //excelReader.GetInt32(0);
}

excelReader.Close();
```