# Como ler um arquivo excel em c# e salvar os dados em strings?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Galera,preciso fazer uma aplicação de console c# que lê um Excel e salva cada dado em uma string!!Já tentei várias bibliotecas e nada deu certo

Comment: Uma pesquisa talvez resolvesse seu problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23080/trabalhando-com-dados-do-excel-no-c

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso o GemBox.Spreadsheet 3.7 for .NET 3.0 - 4.5 para fazer importação de Excel

```
protected void lnkValidar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(FileUpload.FileName);
            string fileExtension = finfo.Extension.ToLower();
            if (fileExtension != ".xlsx")
            {
                lblErro.UserError("Selecione um arquivo no formato .xlsx");
                return;
            }

            Stream fileStream = FileUpload.FileContent;
            var RetornoDados = ConverteExcelExcelFile(fileStream);

                var Msg = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var sheet in RetornoDados.Worksheets)
                {
                    foreach (var row in sheet.Rows.Where(R => R.Index > 0))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Msg.Clear();
                            String Coluna0 = (Convert.ToString(row.AllocatedCells[0].Value)).Trim();
                            String Coluna1 = (Convert.ToString(row.AllocatedCells[1].Value)).Trim();
                            String Coluna2 = (Convert.ToString(row.AllocatedCells[2].Value)).Trim();
                            String Coluna3 = (Convert.ToString(row.AllocatedCells[3].Value)).Trim();

                         }
                        catch (Exception exc)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Erro ");
                        }
                    }
                    break;     // Só o 1o sheet !
                }
        }
    }
}

public ExcelFile ConverteExcelExcelFile(Stream fileStream)
{
    SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("000000000000000"); // entre no site e pegue uma licença 
    return ExcelFile.Load(fileStream, LoadOptions.XlsxDefault);            
}
```

Ou o  Open XML ...

```
            if (FileUpload.HasFile)
            {
                FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(FileUpload.FileName);
                string fileExtension = finfo.Extension.ToLower();
                if (fileExtension != ".xlsx")
                {
                    lblErro.UserError("Selecione um arquivo no formato .xlsx");
                    return;
                }

                Stream fileStream = FileUpload.FileContent;
                var retorno = Upload(fileStream);

                if (retorno is string)
                {
                  //erro
                }
                else
                {
                    // todo
                }
            }


    private Object Upload(Stream fileStream)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileStream, false))
        {
            IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();
            try
            {
                foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(0))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell));
                }
            }
            catch
            {                   
                    throw;
            }             
            try
            {
                int index = 0;

                foreach (Row row in rows)
                {
                    DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();

                    // Menor que a quantidade de colunas da planilha ... index
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count(); i++) // index
                    {
                        tempRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                return dt;
            }
        }

        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
        return dt;
    }


    public static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
    {
        SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
        string value = "";
        if (cell.CellValue != null)
            value = cell.CellValue.InnerText;

        if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
        {
            return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Esse componente só tem versão paga?

Comment: a licença free dele é limitada ... 150 linha. veja no site http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/free-version

Comment: Um componente também que pode ser usado é o  OpenXml... vou posta um exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Augusto Bueno, como não citou outros detalhes apenas a leitura do arquivo excel, se o arquivo vai conter campos fixos e etc. [Este exemplo, http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1895/lendo-um-arquivo-do-excel-%E2%80%9Cxls%E2%80%9D-com-csharp.aspx](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1895/lendo-um-arquivo-do-excel-%E2%80%9Cxls%E2%80%9D-com-csharp.aspx) esta pode auxiliar a conduzir para uma direção.

Answer (score 1):

Eu já utilize a ExcelLib(https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/); pesquisei agora e vi que consta como projeto arquivado...

A vantagem é manipular(criando, abrindo, salvando, etc.) sem a necessidade de ter o MSOffice instalado(com a limitação de ser apenas para ".xls").

Talvez seja até mais do que você precisa.

Bom trabalho